# Batch : List files recursively with path and size in a txt

Tags: batch-file, recursion

Trying to list recursively all files with only path, name and size of a folder with output in a txt. 
I'm planning to do it for two folders and compare the 2 output txt to see if they're identical.

For now I tried that :

`@echo off
for /R "F:\Folder1\MyFolder\" %A in (*.*) do echo %~pnA %~zA > output.txt`

But for now it seems the recursivity doesn't work in my case cause I obtain :

```
\Folder\MyFolder\MyFile 23617195
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to append the result:

```
for /R "F:\Folder1\MyFolder\" %A in (*.*) do echo %~pnA %~zA >> output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, that works ! 
Second question :
the folders analyse are save folders. I need to see if the files are identical so I look at names and sizes. Would comp work for this case ?

Comment: @vincs2 - you can check (FC)[http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html] command with which you can compare two files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like that if you want :

```
@echo off 
Set LogFile=Path_Size.txt
if exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
Set Folder=c:\test
(
    for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b %Folder%') do (
        echo "%%~fa" & Call:GetSize %%a & echo ******************
        )
)>>%LogFile% 2>nul
Start "" %LogFile%
pause

:GetSize
(
echo wscript.echo GetSize("%~1"^)
echo Function GetSize(MyFile^)
echo    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo    Set objFile= fso.GetFile(MyFile^)  
echo    GetSize = FormatSize(objFile.Size^)
echo End Function
echo '*******************************************************************
echo 'Function to format a number into typical size scales
echo Function FormatSize(iSize^)
echo    aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"^)
echo    For i = 0 to 4
echo        If iSize ^> 1024 Then
echo            iSize = iSize / 1024
echo        Else
echo            Exit For
echo        End If
echo    Next
echo    FormatSize = Round(iSize,2^) ^& " " ^& aLabel(i^)
echo End Function
echo '*******************************************************************
)>%tmp%\Size.vbs
Cscript /NoLogo %tmp%\Size.vbs
Del %tmp%\Size.vbs
Exit /b
```